# Jboss 7 request Timeout after sometime

Tags: http, jboss, jboss7.x

One of my service checks my Jboss7 every one minute by hitting a request at

```
http://localhost:8080/check.htm.
```

I have Jboss7 configured with apache for rest of the world. The problem is, after a few hours of start up, it stops responding to my service and service then restarts the jboss by killing the processes.

Went through logs and did all the research. But no clue. Please help

Comment: Could you provide some logs or more information?

Comment: There is nothing in log. Last INFO msg is showing (which is logged by application) and then from next line, the server startup logs start coming.

Comment: Have you tried to access the url from a web browser (or using something like wget)? What's the error returned to the client? Do you see any log trace when you try to access the URL?

Comment: It runs smoothly. Just that on a particular time it happens. I think something building up and when it reaches the peak, server stops responding. In my services log, it says connection=successful, then request time out.

Comment: And what about other possible requests to other applications in the same JBoss? Do they still work? Have you checked if the number of threads available is properly configured considering the load of the server?

Comment: Yes I have already increased http and ajp thread counts

Comment: Other requests also go for timeout.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using hibernate then this problem occurs when your jboss is idle for more than 8 hours.

If so,then

To solve this  you need to configure c3p0 properties in hibernate.cfg.xml

For reference and example [here is configuration](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-configure-the-c3p0-connection-pool-in-hibernate/)

Comment: No,it doesnt remain idle for more than 1 minute. After every minute I am hitting a url which accesses db via hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes so it was a bug in Jboss I suppose. I had to disable the JSP Tag Pooling feature of Jboss 7. This was causing a memory leak and could be tracked easily by following the pattern in GC logs.